# GLUON 4.0 - I cannot use FloatingActionButton in my Application

Tags: gluon-mobile

I migrated my Gluon Mobile Application from 3.0 to 4.0

After that, I cannot include a FloatingActionButton in my application.

This is my class:

...

public class DermatologosPresenter {

```
@FXML
private View visitasDermatologos;

public void initialize() {

    FloatingActionButton fab = new FloatingActionButton();

    fab.setOnAction(e -> {
        System.out.println("HELLO");
    });

    visitasDermatologos.getLayers().add(fab);

    visitasDermatologos.setShowTransitionFactory(BounceInRightTransition::new);
```

...

I have this error in my Netbeans:

[image]

Javier

Answer (score 1):

You have to use:

```
view.getLayers().add(fab.getLayer())
```